# Removing the empty Object/Objects from a complex output

Tags: javascript

Using the map (several map getting the necessary elements inside the nested json) function I am trying to get an output from the Neo4j database according to desired template. During the last map I am building part of desired output having this stored inside variable:

```
 px.segments.map(function(pathSegment){                                                                                          
 individual_path.push({                          
 "start": pathSegment.start.properties.name,
 "weight": pathSegment.relationship.properties.Weight.low,
  "end": pathSegment.end.properties.name}); 
  })
```

Then, depending on what I do have inside the DB and Cypher queries used, in some cases I get, while executing:

```
 console.log(individual_path);
```

I get something like:

```
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },
   { start: 'metadata', weight: 39, end: 'filmID' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },
   { start: 'metadata', weight: 39, end: 'filmID' } ]
 []
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' } ]
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' },
   { start: 'moviesSchema', weight: 39, end: 'title' } ]
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' },
   { start: 'moviesSchema', weight: 39, end: 'title' },
   { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
```

My goal is to avoid the empty objects which can occur inside the output, as I need to use this exactly in the form (start: , weight: , end:). At the end I need to have something like (without empty):

```
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },
   { start: 'metadata', weight: 39, end: 'filmID' } ]
 [ { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },
   { start: 'metadata', weight: 39, end: 'filmID' } ]
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' } ]
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' },
   { start: 'moviesSchema', weight: 39, end: 'title' } ]
 [ { start: 'movieID', weight: 39, end: 'moviesSchema' },
   { start: 'moviesSchema', weight: 39, end: 'title' },
   { start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' } ]
```

Comment: I believe you are logging it in a loop, just validate by `if (individual_path.length) { // array is not empty }`

Comment: Yes, you are completely right it is a loop and thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array by checking if the object is not empty like

```js
let array = [{},{},{ start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },{ start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },{ start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },{ start: 'title', weight: 39, end: 'metadata' },{},{}];

array = array.filter(obj => Object.entries(obj).length !== 0 );
console.log(array);
```

But in the question, you have an empty array `[]` which I presume you want to remove, then do.

```
if (individual_path.length){
    console.log(individual_path);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**IGNORE THIS ANSWER - incorrect**
You can use `filter` on the `individual_path` Array.

```
var newObject = individual_path.filter(item => item.length > 0);
```

This will get all the items which aren't 'empty'. 
Please note this requires `individual_path` to be an array of arrays.

Comment: This doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/b9u2qjdf/, the op has an array of objects, not an "array of arrays"

Comment: Ah you are right! I thought he was showing an array of arrays of objects as the response! I didn't realise he was giving multiple examples.